# Technique for naming a device used to transform objects

Tags: technique, naming

There's this device that I'm writing about which can be used to transform objects.

It can transform anything into anything.

This is in the fictional future where people learned to modify our reality.

The name could either be related or unrelated to what the device actually does.

What about the technique or approach I could take on naming this device?

Maybe you can help me with the naming technique.

Currently using `Metaformer` but it doesn't sound good.

Comment: You should help us and give some details about the context. Does this device take place in a fantasy story ? a Sci-fi one ? What sort of things can be transformed with the device ?

Comment: @StéphaneMourey Added some context, hope it could help a bit.

Comment: First thing that came to mind for me was the Transmogrifier from Calvin & Hobbes. You might want a shorter, snappier name, though.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Joshua*! This looks like you are asking us what to write, which is off-topic. Could you [edit] your question to be more generic and applicable to a wider audience, for example by focussing on techniques for naming devices in fiction with a certain more generic set of functions? That would give you your answer and might be on-topic here. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: I don't think any of us will be able to supply that perfect name for your invention. However we can supply a technique that can help you ignore this naming issue for now and continue writing until you found this perfect name.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus Yes, a technique would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The simplest one is putting brackets - {} - [] - around your current name. And just string replace the word with brackets when you discover the perfect name. This does require you to remember to put brackets around the name you want to have replaced later on. You can do the same with naming people.

Comment: Um... Magic Wand?

Comment: "It can transform anything to anything" - careful there, it sounds like it can transform a language into another language, like a *universal translator* might do. If in fact it could only transform one clump of matter into a second clump of matter, you might be dealing with a *universal transformer.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just found an article that is *right* up your street. It's way too long for me to read, but I skimmed through it and I think that if you're looking for a technique for naming tech then you'll find it very interesting. The article is [The Weird Science of Naming New Products](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/01/18/magazine/the-weird-science-of-naming-new-products.html).

Generally though, here's a selection of techniques for naming new things:

- Variant of the name of the inventor/discoverer. Famous examples are Kalashnikov, Galvanometer and Hoover.
- A word that describes what the machine does. Examples are computer, electricity generator and metaformer.
- A word for the main technology the tech uses. Examples are vacuum cleaner and lithium battery.
- Random (but (sometimes) powerful sounding) words, e.g. Tiger/Leopard/Lion (Mac OS) and Jelly Bean/Ice Cream Sandwich/Gingerbread (Android OS).
- Concatenated words (as used in Germanic languages), such as handschuhe (glove - literally hand shoe) and dudelsack (bagpipes - literally yodel sack).

Alternatively, here are [7 Silly Tech Company Naming Trends](http://time.com/70206/silly-tech-company-naming-trends/).

Comment: Great suggestions! Just to note, naming the device after someone gives you huge scope. It could be in the format of “the [surname] [function]”, where surname could be the inventor herself, or someone (with a snappy name!) that the inventor wants to commemorate (gives you licence to add a sub-story on that). And function could be “drive”, “box”, “ray”, “machine”, “tube”, etc.

Comment: Nice one, @Chappo! :)